# Accessing model/class information within context processor

Tags: django

In my Django app I have a series of generic views (create, update, delete, detail, list) that most of my actual views inherit from.  All of these views add a number of pieces of useful information to the context (the singular and plural names of the model, the urls for creating, listing, etc).  But the views more-or-less all duplicate the same code.  For that reason I'd like to move these things to a context processor and remove the code duplication.

My issue is, I can't seem to determine the things I would need from the request that's passed to the context processor (ie: if I could access the model instance, model class, form class, etc), then Id be fine.  The code below shows what the get_context_data looks like within the views - how would I replicate this in a context processor?

Thanks.

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    """Passes context variables to the HTML templates."""
    context = super(CodexAnonDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['model_name'] = model_ngettext(self.model, 1)
    context['model_name_plural'] = model_ngettext(self.model, 2)
    context['object_create_url'] = reverse('%s:%s_create' % (resolve(self.request.path).app_name, self.model.__name__))
    context['model_list_url'] = reverse('%s:%s_list' % (resolve(self.request.path).app_name, self.model.__name__))
```

Answer (score 0):

The beauty of Django's class based views is that you can take advantage of class inheritance to implement shared functionality

Define a class that implements the behavior you require and then inherit from both the generic view class and your mixin

```
class MyMixin(object):

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(MyMixin, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['model_name'] = model_ngettext(self.model, 1)
        context['model_name_plural'] = model_ngettext(self.model, 2)
        context['object_create_url'] = reverse('%s:%s_create' % (resolve(self.request.path).app_name, self.model.__name__))
        context['model_list_url'] = reverse('%s:%s_list' % (resolve(self.request.path).app_name, self.model.__name__))
        return context


class MyCreateView(MyMixin, CreateView):

    model = MyModel
```